# Deploying Node.js API with MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, deployment, server

I've been developing a game using Unity3D as part of my master's degree thesis. The game communicates with a Node.js RestAPI, which handles the requests and the data in a MongoDB database.

During development, I've been using my pc as a localhost, however now I'm ready for testing which means I need to deploy the Node.js RestAPI and MongoDB to a server.

In order to get the machine, I've been asked to write a proper request highlighting the technologies/technical requirements I need.
Having never done this before, I'm currently having trouble figuring out what I need.

I know I need the machine to have Node.js Express and MongoDB installed or, at least, I need the permissions to install them. However, in terms of the machine's OS, I have no idea.

Which OS is the best for Node.js+MongoDB deployment?

As I have never done this before, am I missing any requirements?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of option to deploy your application RESTful API. I don't have much idea about the OS but here are tons of platform listed on Node.js official GitHub repository.
Visit https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Node-Hosting

Comment: Thank you! That will be very helpful in the future, I am sure.
 
Thank you! That will be very helpful in the future, I am sure. However, I'm not in a position to be too picky. I believe I will only be able to choose from Linux or Windows. My question intent was to figure out if saying the OS I want, besides the Node.js and MongoDB technologies, was the only  "requirement" I need to specify.

Answer (score 1):

https://itsfoss.com/nodeos-operating-system/
https://node-os.com/

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver) is the best OS for Node.js + MongoDB deployment and NodeOS

NodeOS, the operating system based on Node.js, is now heading towards its version 1.0 following the release of its first Release Candidate last year.

If this is the first time you’re hearing about it, NodeOS is the first ever operating system powered by Node.js & npm and built on top of the Linux Kernel. Jacob Groundwater introduced this project in mid-2013. The primary technologies used in building the system are:

Linux Kernel: The entire OS is built on the Linux Kernel.
Node.js runtime: Node is used as the primary runtime.
npm Packages: npm is used for package management.
NodeOS source is hosted on Github Repository. So, anybody interested can easily contribute and report bugs. Users can build from source or use the pre-built images available. The build process and quick start guide can be found at project repository.

Comment: Thank you.

But as I said in the comment above, I can't be that picky. What I'm looking for is the confirmation that the Os, Node.js and MongoDB technologies are the only requirements I need to mention in my formal request!